# Compacity of the Heat semigroup on Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators, linear-pde

Consider, on $\Omega=(0,1),$ the unbounded operator $A=\Delta, \,$ (the Laplacean operator) with domain $D(A)=\{y\in W^{2,p}(0,1)/ y'(0)=0 \;\&\; y'(1)=0\}$.

I am wondering if the operator $A$ is the infinitesimal  generator of a compact semigroup on $L^p(0,1)$ for $p>1$?

Comment: Is *compacity* a term in actual use by professionals in the field, or a mistaken version of *compactness* ?

Comment: that is, $A $ generates a semigroup $S(t)$ which is compact for $t>0$.

Comment: in the sense that : if $x_n$ tends to $0$ weakly in $L^p(0,1),$ then for $t>0$, the sequence $S(t)x_n$ tends to $0$ strongly in $L^p(0,1).$